# Use same ComplexType in different WSDL files

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, soa, complextype

I would like to use same ComplexType in two different WSDLs. How to define and include these ComplexTypes so i can use it in both WSDLs? (and practically in case of Java they are generated to the same package/datatype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really dependent on your deployment model etc. But here is a simple solution

- Let that complex type be in its own namespace
- Bundle the complex type as a separate component on its own say COMMON-XSD

For each WSDL

- IMPORT the complex type
- Put a dependency on the COMMON-XSD
- Use the facilities provided by your build tool to copy the XSD to this project (mvn and ant can do it)
- Most wsdl-to-java tools allow you to map the COMMON-XSD namespace to whatever package you want
- Generate code for WSDL

I suggest you go through this [nice article](http://www.gridshore.nl/blog/index.php?/archives/68-Web-service-versioning-in-the-java-world.html).

I can provide more specific answers if you include more details on your build env and deployment model

Comment: I have three layers, where object/type is passed between them. Every layer is represented by client/server with own WSDL which are used by CXF generator. Layer1 is server for Layer2, Layer2 is server for Layer3 and client for Layer1. Its obvious that because of separate WSDL files, "same" object passing from L1 to L3 has different datatype (complextype is defined and generated twice to different packages for L1 and L2)

Comment: so L3 -> L2 -> L1 is the flow and the same ComplexType is being passed across layers. This doesn't cause any issues as long as each layer treats it as a different obj than the one it supports. Classic namespace problem solved by using packages in Java and namespaces in XML ;-). You might be able to solve in other ways but that just complicates things. Just stick with a diff namespace for the complex type and diff package structre while generating code as i have suggested

Comment: Yes, I have it realized in diff NS and packages. But in this case you can't just simply pass object to next layer because its treated as different type and you have to unsightly copy all properties to same object from right package. Not mention things when you want edit ComplexType later.